# How to load non-standard characters from file using SBCL Common Lisp?

Tags: file-io, character-encoding, common-lisp, sbcl

Trying
loading contents of file containing one line with word: `λέξη`

```
(with-open-file (s PATH-TO-FILE :direction :input)
  (let ((a (read-line s)))
    (print a)))
```

outputs

```
""
T
```

Trying:

```
(with-open-file (s PATH-TO-FILE :direction :input)
  (let ((buffer ""))
    (do ((character (read-char s nil) (read-char s nil)))
        ((null character))
      (setf buffer (concatenate 'string buffer (format nil "~a" character))))
    (format t "~a" buffer)))
```

outputs

```
funny characters (nothing like the original contents)
T
```

What I would like to do is to load all lines of file containing such non-standard characters.
Then I want to be able to output these words to console or via LTK widgets (text on button for example).

Comment: What happens when you evaluate `(setf sb-impl::*default-external-format* :utf-8)` and try again?

Comment: I changed coding to UTF8 in input file then I added your proposed line to second version of code and evaluated. Output is: `?????` newline `T`. First version with added this additional line still outputs `""` newline `T`

Comment: Thank you for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass [`:external-format X`](http://www.sbcl.org/manual/#External-Formats) to [`with-open-file`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_w_open.htm), where
`X` is the actual encoding used in the file (`:utf-8` or [`:ISO-8859-7`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-7) or whatever).

```
(with-open-file (stream PATH-TO-FILE :external-format :utf-8)
  (let ((line (read-line stream)))
    (loop :for char :across line :do 
       (print (list (char-name char) (char-code char))))
    line))
```

Since it prints

```
("ZERO_WIDTH_NO-BREAK_SPACE" 65279) 
("GREEK_SMALL_LETTER_LAMDA" 955) 
("GREEK_SMALL_LETTER_EPSILON_WITH_TONOS" 941) 
("GREEK_SMALL_LETTER_XI" 958) 
("GREEK_SMALL_LETTER_ETA" 951)
```

you can see that you are, indeed, reading the file correctly.

Your problem now if how to *print* those non-ASCII characters to the screen, and that is an entirely different question.

Comment: It still outputs `?????` if I use :utf-8 and file was "saved as" using UTF-8 coding.

Comment: it does not mean that it read wrong - it might be printing wrong.

Comment: Hmm. Could you please tell me how do I output it then? And generally how to handle it?

Comment: try my code. what does it print?

Comment: "While evaluating the form starting at line 25, column 0 (...) debugger invoked on  UNBOUND-VARIABLE in thread (...) The variable C is unbound."
Also warns of undefined variables:
ACROSS
C
DO
PRINT
undefined function:
FOR

Comment: sorry, it was a typo - insert `loop` before `for`

Comment: I also added "()" for print. Output is one number each line: `65279` `955` `941` `958` `951`

Comment: Okay, so now you can use `char-name` and `code-char` (see yet another edit) to ascertain that you are indeed reading the characters correctly.

Comment: Looks like it works, it outputs things like: ("GREEK_SMALL_LETTER_ETA 951).

Comment: okay, so now you should [close this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/215439) and ask another one - how to _print_ non-ASCII.

Comment: OK, thank you for help!